# View no refresh validation messages with ko.extenders/navigation property in breeze entity

Tags: knockout.js, breeze, durandal, hottowel

I have a SPA with hottowel (Breeze 1.4.5, Durandal 2.0.1, Knockout 3.0.0, Bootstrap 3.0, jquery 2.0.3) and I validated with ko.extenders in client views and all work perfectly but when I extend an observable (navigation property) with ko.extenders the validation didn't work but and error messages didn't show in view. I have the next classes:

```
public class Animal
{
    public Animal()
    {
        Actions = new List<Action>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }        
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Action> Actions { get; set; }
}

public class Action
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int AnimalId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int ActionTypeId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

The view:

```
<div data-bind="with: animal">
<input data-bind="value: name"/>
<div data-bind="foreach: actions">
    <div>
        <p data-bind="css: { errorMessageForm: name.hasError }">
            <input type="text" data-bind="value: name, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'" maxlength="128" />
            <span data-bind="visible: name.hasError, text: name.validationMessage"></span>
            <span data-bind="visible: name.hasError, text: 'Has Error'"></span>
            <span data-bind="visible: !name.hasError(), text: 'No Has Error'"></span>
        </p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p data-bind="css: { errorMessageForm: description.hasError }">
            <input type="text" data-bind="value: description, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'" maxlength="128" />
            <span data-bind="visible: description.hasError, text: description.validationMessage"></span>
        </p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p data-bind="css: { errorMessageForm: actionTypeId.hasError }">
            <select data-bind="options: $root.actionTypes, optionsText: 'name', optionsValue: 'id', value: actionTypeId, valueUpdate: 'change'"></select>
            <span data-bind="visible: actionTypeId.hasError, text: actionTypeId.validationMessage"></span>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
<button data-bind="click: $root.addAction"><span>Add Action</span></button>
```

The code of `addAction`:

```
addAction = function () {
            var action = datacontext.createAction();
            //add validators
            action.actionTypeId.extend({ intRequired: 'The action type is required' });
            action.name.extend({ required: 'The name is required' });
        }
```

The code of `createAction`:

```
function createAction() {
        var initialValues = {
            animalId: getCurrentAnimalId()
        };
        var action = manager.createEntity(entityNames.action, initialValues);

        return action;
    }
```

The extenders to validate are equal in page [Using extenders to augment observables](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/extenders.html).

The `validationMessage` of property `actionTypeId` and `name` wasn't show.

I put breakpoints to verify values of `validationMessage` and `hasError` in the `viewmodel` and It had the correct values but in the view didn't show `validationMessages`.

After I added this lines in html view for verify state of validation:

```
<span data-bind="visible: name.hasError, text: 'Has Error'"></span>
<span data-bind="visible: !name.hasError(), text: 'No has Error'"></span>
```

I had test de SPA, later of add new action with button `addAction` the view shows twice duplicated input html control, then I enter a value in one input `name` and the validation messages appears but only in one input html control, in the second input html control (duplicated) the validation messages didn't appear.

The next line caused the twice duplicated of "input html control":

```
<span data-bind="visible: !name.hasError(), text: 'No has Error'"></span>
```

The view no refresh the validation messages with ko.extenders in navigation property items from breeze entity.

I had tested all again but I haven't used Breeze for create entities, only I have used simple object and all work perfectly... but I really need to use Breeze to create entities.

Comment: Try to use the `validationMessage` binding:  `<span data-bind="visible: name.hasError, validationMessage: name"></span>`

Comment: I tried the binding `<span data-bind="visible: name.hasError, validationMessage: name"></span>` but in the view nothing was shown.

Comment: I had tested all again but I haven't used Breeze for create entities, only I have used simple object and all work perfectly... but I really need to use Breeze to create entities.

Comment: Here's a shot in the dark. Inside `createAction` before returning, try `action.animal.valueHasMutated()` or even `setTimeout(function(){action.animal.valueHasMutated();}, 0);`. These steps might compensate for a possible timing problem. Let us know and then we can suggest something better perhaps.

Comment: FWIW, I'm not a fan of validating in the View layer which is KO validation is about. Breeze entities have built in validation support. What's missing for KO is a custom binding to display errors. Need to write one comparable to the [`zValidate` Angular attribute](http://www.breezejs.com/breeze-labs/breezedirectivesvalidationjs). Who wants to beat me to it? :-)